# I don't understand the new functions line. why is it there?

Tags: function

```
public class Programme {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String adminstrator;                                    // initiate Adminstator variable
        Functions fun= new Functions();                         
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);                // initiating keyboard inputs
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input Administrator name: ");  //asking for administrators name

        adminstrator=sc.nextLine();                             // setting adminstrator name
```

Comment: What this line does is instantiate a new instance of class `Functions`. Beyond that, there's nothing we can help you with, since its not a built-in Java class, it's part of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really common in Java. Maybe you come from another programming languague (let's say, c++). 
In Java, doing *Functions fun;* only says that fun is a reference to an object of class Functions, but doesn't create any object. In c++, it would be like doing *Functions* fun;*.

Doing *Functions fun= new Functions();* says that fun is a reference to an object of class Functions, but also creates a new object of that class and assigns it to fun.